# ajax content (post) in a jquery dialog not loading on the second loading of the dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog

I have a page where I load a dialog on click of a button:

```
function editShowSchedule(emId){
    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");            
    var url = "inc/ajax/schedule-editShowSchedule.php?emId="+emId+"&stationId="+<?php echo $stationId;?>;   
    var container = '<div id="somediv" title="Modifier l\'horaire d\'une émission"></div>';
    $(container).load(url).dialog({
       //modal:false,
       height: 600,
       width: 600,
       resizable: false,
       buttons: { "Annuler": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); },
               "Sauvegarder": function(){ saveShowSchedule();} }
    });
}
```

Then, in that dialog, I trigger  .change() on my drop down box to load the infos relative to the selected element.

```
<?php 
$emId = $_POST['emId'];
$stationId = $_POST['stationId'];
?>
```

[...]

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#selectShow").unbind('change');
$("#selectShow").change(function(){
    $("#showTimelines").html('En chargement');
    var emId = $("#selectShow").val();
    var stationId = <?php echo $stationId;?>;
    var params = {emId:emId,
                  stationId:stationId}
    $.post('inc/ajax/schedule-getAllTimelinesByEmId.php',params, function(data){ 
            alert('getTimelineByEmId');
            $("#showTimelines").html(data);             
            $(".button, button, input:submit, input:button").button();  
            enableAddRecurrenceInPeriod();
            enableRecurrenceCloseBox();
        },"html"  
    ); 
})<?php if($emId > 0){?>.change()<?php }?>;
});
```

The first time around, it works fine.

But if I close the dialog box and just click to open it again, then the alert actually works, but I see nothing appearing in the $("#showTimelines").html (not even the loading message:$("#showTimelines").html('En chargement');), even though I do see it in firefox and I made the post only after the document is loaded...

Anybody knows why and/or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I got it. Thanks Felipe for leading me on the right track:
I changed my jquery to this:

```
function editShowSchedule(emId){
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("destroy");  
$("#somediv").remove();     
var url = "inc/ajax/schedule-editShowSchedule.php?emId="+emId+"&stationId="+<?php echo $stationId;?>;   
var container = '<div id="somediv" title="Modifier l\'horaire d\'une émission"></div>';
$(container).load(url).dialog({
    //modal:false,
    height: 600,
    width: 600,
    resizable: false,
    close: function(event, ui){
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
        $("#somediv").remove();
    },
    buttons: { "Annuler": function() { $(this).dialog("destroy"); 
                                       $("#somediv").remove(); },
               "Sauvegarder": function(){ saveShowSchedule();} }
});
```

}

Basically, the close was effectively only hiding the dialog. Using destroy now erases it, but it left the container in place, although hidden, (thus updating that one instead of the new dialog created with my ajax), so I removed it completely by calling $("#somediv").remove();

Now, everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you split those two steps: create the dialog once (at document ready, for example), and just call 'open' at the click of the button (you can still update the inner html of the dialog normally).

From [jquery ui docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/):

A call to $(foo).dialog() will initialize a dialog instance and will auto-open the dialog by default. 
If you want to **reuse a dialog, the easiest way is to disable the "auto-open" option** with:

```
$(foo).dialog({ autoOpen: false }) 
  and open it with
$(foo).dialog('open'). 
  To close it, use 
$(foo).dialog('close')
```

Comment: So the problem would come from the fact that I actually close it? 
Does that mean that I have to overwrite the close on the X to just hide it? Because in my case, I open the dialog, load the content, close the dialog. Reopen a new(?) dialog, load the content (but I can't see it although it was fetch in firebug).

The way you seem to say it, I should open a dialog, update it, hide it, update and show it again,... and close it?

Comment: The problem seems to be the fact you're initializing a dialog that was already initialized. After you called the .dialog() for the first time (initialized the component), you can just call .dialog('open') or .dialog('close') to change it's visibility.